# Replace values into previous row with a condition

Tags: r, substring, str-replace, data-manipulation

I want to get data where ID column doesn´t start with 00 and append this value of ID column to the end of Description column in previous row.

Then replace the rest of values into after Name column in the previous row. How can I do that with R?

Here is source of dummy data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SbmaM8hXck-z5nsNfDMbhwijvAGPkPPBgQ_eY4JAMC8/edit?usp=sharing

```
ID      Year    Description  Name   User       Factor_1  Factor_2   Factor_3
0011    2016    blue colour  AA     James      Xfac      NA         NA
is nice XXX     XLM          Yfac   different  Yfac      NA         NA
0024    2017    red colour   DD     Mark       Zfac      NA         NA
is good YYY     STM          Lfac   unique     Zfac      NA         NA
```

What I want to have:

```
ID      Year    Description          Name   User  Factor_1   Factor_2   Factor_3
0011    2016    blue colour is nice  XXX    XLM   Yfac       different  Yfac
0024    2017    red colour is good   YYY    STM   Lfac       unique     Zfac
```

Comment: does the non-zero ID value always follow 00 value in ID?

Comment: please provide the sample data using `dput`, so we know what we are working with...

Comment: @YOLO Yes, right

Comment: @Wimpel I added the link above as source of sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the first part where you want to paste the descriptions together, 
and there's the part where you want to move your variables as well, as you want "XXX" and "YYY" in your "user" column.

Also, in Viveks answer all wrong lines are pasted with ALL "right" lines, which works in your example, but not if you have a few right lines, and then a wrong one.
Working with booleans (TRUE/FALSE) sometimes works fine, but in this case, I think you want to use an integer index, as that makes it easier to refer to "the previous line". Which gives me code:

```
rmlines <- which(!substr(df$ID,1,2)=="00")
df$Description[rmlines-1] <- paste(df$Description[rmlines-1], df[rmlines,1], sep=" ")
df[rmlines-1, 4:8] <- df[rmlines, 2:6]
df <- df[-rmlines,]
```

But there's one more problem to consider: what classes are your columns?
When I tried it out, I treated everything as a character, which means you can move columns around fine. In your data, some may be factors or something else, so you might want to change the classes. I think it's easiest to first change it all to character, and then change it (back) to the final class you want your columns to be.

```
# To change everything to character:
df <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, as.character), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# And to assign the right classes, you need to decide case-by-case:
df$Year <- as.integer(df$Year)
df$Factor_1 <- as.factor(df$Factor1) # Optionally provide levels
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It worked but I need to find a more robust solution in case I have lots of columns with NAs. Can you please take a look into that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53610694/replace-values-into-previous-row-where-the-last-non-na-row

Comment: It doesn't really matter what the content of the columns is, NA or something else. To just move more columns you can replace the 4:8 and 2:6 with e.g. 4:100 and 2:98, or if you don't know how many you have you can use `4:ncol(df)` and `2:(ncol(df)-2). It only means that the last 2 columns of the lines you are shifting right" get discarded. If you don't want that you can use `4:(ncol(df)+2)` and `2:ncol(df)`, that way two new columns are created, which are filled with NA's for column where you don't assign anything.

Comment: Yes, I did, like above and worked. But this time condition is different. Instead of pasting rows to a specific order, I need to paste them into the end of last non-NA row which can be different for each row. If you look at dummy data on the link, I think you better understand what I mean. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53610694/replace-values-into-previous-row-where-the-last-non-na-row

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  bind_cols(df %>% rename_all(function(x) paste0(x, "_dummy"))) %>%
  mutate(
    Description = ifelse(substr(lead(ID), 1, 2) != "00", 
                         paste(Description, lead(ID)), Description),
    Name = lead(Year_dummy),
    User = lead(Description_dummy),
    Factor_1 = lead(Name_dummy),
    Factor_2 = lead(User_dummy),
    Factor_3 = lead(Factor_1_dummy)
  ) %>% select(-ends_with("dummy")) %>%
  filter(substr(ID, 1, 2) == "00")
```

Output:

```
    ID Year       Description Name User Factor_1  Factor_2 Factor_3
1 0011 2016 blue colour is nice  XXX  XLM     Yfac different     Yfac
2 0024 2017  red colour is good  YYY  STM     Lfac    unique     Zfac
```

In case you're dealing with a large number of columns, a combination of `dplyr` and `base` R could do it:

```
library(dplyr)

df_combo <- cbind(df, df)

df$Description <- ifelse(substr(lead(df$ID), 1, 2) != "00", 
                               paste(df$Description, lead(df$ID)), df$Description)

for (i in (ncol(df) + 4):ncol(df_combo)) {

  df_combo[[i]] <- lead(df_combo[[i - ncol(df) - 2]])

}

df_combo <- subset(df_combo, substr(ID, 1, 2) == "00")

df_descr <- subset(df, substr(ID, 1, 2) == "00")

df_final <- df_combo[, (ncol(df) + 1):ncol(df_combo)]

df_final$Description <- df_descr$Description

rm(df_descr, df_combo)
```

Output:

```
     ID Year       Description Name User Factor_1  Factor_2 Factor_3
1: 0011 2016 blue colour is nice  XXX  XLM     Yfac different     Yfac
2: 0024 2017  red colour is good  YYY  STM     Lfac    unique     Zfac
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have lots of other columns beyond last column. How can I paste them the same way from where ID column doesn´t start with 00 into previous row? Added select(-ends_with("dummy"), everything()), but number of columns increased two times.

Comment: Unfortunately in this case you'd have to do it manually. Let's say that you have a column named X in which you'd like to paste Y in the previous row. You put it inside statement the same way as other, e.g. if we continue from the example here - (.. Factor_3 = lead(Factor_1_dummy), X = lead(Y_dummy)), etc.

Comment: I have 167 columns in total. Is there any alternative way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Thanks! I accepted another answer because that was easy and more understandable to me. But your help worked too! To have a more robust solution for another case, instead of pasting rows to a specific order, I want to paste them into the end of last non-NA row which can be different for each row. Can you please take a look that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53610694/replace-values-into-previous-row-where-the-last-non-na-row

Answer (score 0):

Use -

```
bools <- !substr(df$ID,1,2)=="00"
values <- df[bools,1]
df <- df[!bools,]
df$Description <- paste(df[substr(df$ID,1,2)=="00","Description"],values,sep=" ")
df
```

**Output**

```
    ID Year         Description Name  User Factor_1 Factor_2
1 0011 2016 blue colour is nice   AA James     Xfac       NA
3 0024 2017  red colour is good   DD  Mark     Zfac       NA
  Factor_3
1       NA
3       NA
```

Comment: Description column seems like that: ("blue colour", "red colour") c("is nice", "is good"). Also output is quite different. Here is the sample data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SbmaM8hXck-z5nsNfDMbhwijvAGPkPPBgQ_eY4JAMC8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @kimi_f109 did the code work ? Like I said the output will look different in my case. It should work fine in your case

Comment: Yes, but output is quite different. I don`t know what to change in your code chunk to achieve the result.

Comment: @kimi_f109 like I said you don't have to change anything :-) I have edited ans pls check

Comment: Here is your output when I run the code and it`s not correct result what I want. Please check: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c3-icr6_PI8EMzyeMdOU8AJNw0Xo65mhtK89NrUoQ0g/edit?usp=sharing